# Define palette breaks for leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

Is there a way to define palette breaks based on specific ranges of a variable?
Take a continuous variable x that ranges from 0 to 1 as an example. I defined the `palette` as:

```
palette <- colorNumeric(palette = rev("RdYlGn"), domain = NULL, na.color = NA)
```

and in the corresponding leaflet function, I defined the `color` as:

```
color = ~palette(x)
```

This returns a nice looking map, however, the breaks are defined at an equal space: 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, ..., 1.0

Instead, I defined the breaks as:

```
df@data$x_brks <- cut(x, 
                  breaks=c(0, 0.55, 0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 0.95, 1.0), 
                  labels=c("<=0.55", ">0.55 and <=0.65", ">0.65 and <=0.75", 
                           ">0.75 and <= 0.85", ">0.85 and <=0.95", ">0.95")
                     )
```

and would like to maintain the same palette (the lowest range would be red and the highest range would be green). I am plotting multiple layers and I would like to maintain the same scale for all of them.

I couldn't pass this new variable `x_brks` within the `color = ~palette(x_brks)` function in Leaflet - I get this error: `Error in Summary.factor(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L,  : ‘range’ not meaningful for factors`.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Try colorBin

```
risk.bins <-c(0, 0.55, 0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 0.95, 1.0)
risk.pal <- colorBin("plasma", bins = risk.bins, na.color = "#aaff56")
```

and then in the leaflet function

```
   color = ~ risk.pal(value)
```

Labels can be manually set in addLegend by inserting the text as is

```
labels = c("<=0.55",
           ">0.55 and <=0.65",
           ">0.65 and <=0.75",
           ">0.75 and <= 0.85",
           ">0.85 and <=0.95",
           ">0.95")
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but I can't get the labels to show as defined. I was using the pal with labels which why it didn't work. I changed that to colors and labels but I get an error: 'colors' and 'labels' must be of the same length.
`colors = ~palette(values),
labels= c("<=0.55", ">0.55 and <=0.65", ">0.65 and <=0.75", ">0.75 and <= 0.85", ">0.85 and <=0.95", ">0.95", " ")`
Note: `length(unique(palette(values)))` is 7 which is equal to the length of the label's vector.

Comment: I see 8 in label. what is the last one? a blank space?

Comment: Yes, that is for `NA`, but with it or without it, it does not work and I get the same error.

Comment: This worked but it is not ideal:
`addLegend(map,"bottomright",
colors = c("#D73027", "#FC8D59", "#D9EF8B", "#FEE08B", "#91CF60", "#1A9850"),
labels= c("<=0.55", ">0.55 and <=0.65", ">0.65 and <=0.75", ">0.75 and <= 0.85", ">0.85 and <=0.95", ">0.95"))
`